# check if username, email, twitter account exists in the a database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a registration form where the user insert his contact information:

```
 1. username
 2. email
 3. twitter ID
 4. cell number
```

what I want to do next is to check the database, and if any one of them is already exists I want to show a message to the user to inform him that it is already exists.

**Example:**
if the user inserted username `"jhon"` I want to display a message saying "`username` already exists."

Simply, I just DO NOT want to display a message like "username or email or twitter ID or cell number exists."  The message should define which input is already exists.

here is my code:

**Note: I know I have to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` but I'm using it here for example only**

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '". $username ."' OR  `email` = '". $email ."' OR  `twitterID` = '". $twitterID ."' OR `cellNum` = '". $cellNum ."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        echo 'Username or email or twitter ID or cell number already in use.';
    }
?>
```

I hope I was clear...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhat unorthodox, but what have you tried?

Comment: So you have to select all 4 fields and check what field exists already. Also keep in mind that you can have several records as a result of your query.

Comment: ya, I agree.. Anyway, I've tried using if statements to check for each single field by using a dedicated query.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt it straight forward? Or do I miss something completely obvious?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '". $username ."' OR  `email` = '". $email ."' OR  `twitterID` = '". $twitterID ."' OR `cellNum` = '". $cellNum ."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if (isset($row['username'])) {
   echo 'Username already exists.';
} else if (isset($row['email'])) {
   echo 'Email already exists.';
} else if (isset($row['twitterID'])) {
   echo 'Twitter account already exists.';
} else if (isset($row['cellNum'])) {
   echo 'cellNum account already exists.';
} else {
   echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: If user enters `John + john@mail.org` and there's record `Sammy + john@mail.org` what will your script show? `Username already exists.`?

Comment: I dont know how effectively you sanitize your records. If you can create a user with the username "John + john@mail.org" then yes, it will report "username allready exists".

Comment: @u_mulder is this answer not what the OP wants to achieve?... no duplicates for multi accounts type of thing?

Comment: @LozCherone he *volunteered* with detailed response and **FAILED**. Nobody asked him to, but as long as he's come up with this flawed solution, it makes me wonder why anyone would upvote it. May be upvoters just have no idea how the code works.

Comment: This will only find the 1st that exists, so if there are 2-4, the others will not show. Not sure if this is an issue for the OP, but just to be aware.

Comment: @Sean the whole point is not to allow, 2-4 to be inserted in the first place... so its irrelevant if there are multiple rows...;p

Comment: @Sean, yes - "_The message should define which input is already exists_". If one of the entered values matches the registration cannot continue. If he want to echo them all he can just loop, but I understand this as you can register with _either_ one of the categories, like with a twitter ID **OR** a Cellphone number **OR** a **username** etc, not them all at the same time. But as I wrote, maybe I misunderstood something obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You simply have to check your returned rows for matches:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){ //we know we have something
    $err_out="";
    while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){//Iterate over all rows
        if($username===$r["username"]){ 
            $err_out="Username"; //Set specific error message
            break;
        }else if($twitterID===$r["twitterID"]){
            $err_out="Twitter ID";
            break;
        }else if($cellNum===$r["cellNum"]){
            $err_out="Cellphone number";
            break;
        }else if($email===$r["email"]){
            $err_out="Email";
            break;
        }
    } //while
if($err_out===""){ /*something's wrong, sql injection maybe? */ }
else
    echo "Error: $err_out already exists";
}//if
```

The code at the end is by no means injection prevention, merely a sanity check. It will also stop at the first match, to continue you can do something like

```
if($err_out!=="") $err_out.=", ";
$err_out.="Twitter ID";
```

and of course remove the `break` statement. This would produce something like

```
Error: Username, Twitter ID already exists
```

if you don't mind slightly abusing English ("exists" for multiple items)

Comment: You really just have to examinate the first record, since every record will be a match.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your query (note there are possible sql injection vulnerabilities):

`SELECT 
    (username like '$username') as UsernameExists, 
    (email like '$email') as EmailExists, 
    (twitterID like '$twitterID') AS TwitterIDExists, 
    (cellNum like '$cellNum') as CellExists
WHERE
    username like '$username' OR
    email like '$email' OR
    twitterID like '$twittterID' OR
    cellNum like '$cellNum'`

This sql query will have columns returned like, "UsernameExists" and "CellExists". The values will only ever be 0 or 1. One if the value already exists.

Then after you run your query with mysqli_query, use the following code to find the data that already exists:

```
<?php
$alreadyExist = array();

// Loop through the entire result set from the database. 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // Look through all of the columns in the database. 
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        // If we find that one of the columns has 1, then append to the array of columns that already exist. 
        if ($value == 1) {
            $alreadyExist[] = substr($key, 0, -6);
        }

    }
}
// If we found information that exists in the database, then print out which ones already exist. 
if (!empty($alreadyExist)) echo "The following already exist: ". implode($alreadyExist);
?>
```

Now the full code would look something like the following:

```
<?php

$username = "username";
$email = 'test@test.com';
$twitterID = "@sometwitterID";
$cell = "123.123.1234";

$sql = "
SELECT 
    (A.username like '$username') as UsernameExists, 
    (A.email like '$email') as EmailExists, 
    (A.twitterID like '$twitterID') AS TwitterIDExists, 
    (A.cellNum like '$cell') as CellExists
FROM test.testing A
WHERE
    A.username like '$username' OR
    A.email like '$email' OR
    A.twitterID like '$twitterID' OR
    A.cellnum like '$cell'
";



$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "databasename");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    $alreadyExist = array();

    // Loop through the entire result set from the database. 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // Look through all of the columns in the database. 
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            // If we find that one of the columns has 1, then append to the array of columns that already exist. 
            if ($value == 1) {
                $alreadyExist[] = substr($key, 0, -6);
            }

        }
    }

  mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);



// If we found information that exists in the database, then print out which ones already exist. 
if (!empty($alreadyExist)) 
    echo "The following already exist: ". implode($alreadyExist,", ");
else 
    echo "No Existing Rows!";

?>
```

Comment: I got an error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' (A.email LIKE 'someone@domain.tld') AS , (A.twitter LIKE 'someTwitterID')' at line 2`

Comment: It appears that after AS that you are missing EmailExists. Could be a copy paste issue for you.